# Collection vs ListCollectionView index

Tags: c#, wpf, listcollectionview

I have a ValueConverter that builds a PivotTable that used to have a observableCollection

```
 var employees = values[0] as ObservableCollection<Employee>;
```

And in this converter I set my binding like this:

```
foreach( var employee in employees) {
  int indexer = periods.IndexOf( period );

  var tb = new TextBlock( ) {
    TextAlignment = TextAlignment.Center,
  };

  tb.SetBinding( TextBlock.TextProperty, new Binding( ) {
    ElementName = "root",
    Path = new PropertyPath( "EmployeesCol[" + indexer.ToString( ) + "]." + Extensions.GetPropertyName( ( ) => employee.Name ) )
  } );
}
```

Now my problem is that the binding used to work fine, the path looked like this:

```
EmployeesCol[1].Name
```

But I since have changed the ObservableCollection to a ListCollectionView
So this:

```
var employees = values[0] as ObservableCollection<Employee>;
```

Became this:

```
var employees( (ListCollectionView) values[0] ).Cast<Employee>( ).ToList( );
```

Now this does not work anymore:

```
EmployeesCol[1].Name
```

You cant use the index (indexer) on a ListCollectionView like this, but how can I use the Indexer then on a ListCollectionView to bind to the correct item?

Comment: Did you try `GetItemAt(Int32)` method available on the `ListCollectionView`?

Comment: This wont work on the binding? Because its a string actually being build up, I will then get the error: BindingExpression path error: '[]' property not found on 'object' ''ListCollectionView' (HashCode=13293450)'. BindingExpression:Path=EmployeeCol.GetIndex(1).Name

Comment: The problem is pretty clear from the exception you get, isn't it?! The return value from `GetItemAt(Int32)` is of type `System.Object` which you need to typecast to expected type. For ex: `Employee` in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ListCollectionView`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview(v=vs.110).aspx) provide a method [`object GetItemAt(Int32)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.data.listcollectionview.getitemat(v=vs.110).aspx) to index the collection.

Just a pseudo code based on comments for your understanding would be (of course null reference checks etc. need to be done!!) :

```
var result = (EmployeesCol.GetItemAt(1) as Employee).Name;
```

Answer (score 0):

The `SourceCollection` property of the `ListCollectionView` class returns an `IEnumerable` that you can for example call the `ElementAt` method on or create a list from:

```
var employees = theListCollectionView.SourceCollection.OfType<Employee>().ToList();
var employee = employees[0];
...
var employees = theListCollectionView.SourceCollection.OfType<Employee>();
var employee = employee.ElementAt(0);
```

You can also cast the `SourceCollection` to whatever type your source collection is, like for example a List:

```
var employees = theListCollectionView.SourceCollection as IList<Employee>;
```